# Vesica Piscis shape in Graphics.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, zelle-graphics

I am trying to work through this `Vesica Piscis` shape that
has me puzzled. I tried different methods as objects are drawn
by code order and I have also tried getting the circles to be filled
in white but we can't have only a section of the circle colored.

As of now I am stuck in what should i try and that's
why I am opening myself to suggestions.

I state that what I am trying to achieve is have a white space
keeping all the lines, within the intersection of the two circles
forming the Vesica Piscis shape.

[image: This is what i've done so far.]

```
from graphics import *

def canvas():

    win = GraphWin("Patch", 100, 100)

    for i in range(10):

        lineSet1 = Line(Point(0, 0), Point((i+1)*10, 100))
        lineSet1.draw(win)

        lineSet2 = Line(Point(0, 0), Point(100, (i+1)*10))
        lineSet2.draw(win)

        lineSet3 = Line(Point(100,100), Point(0, 100-(i+1)*10))
        lineSet3.draw(win)

        lineSet4 = Line(Point(100,100), Point(100-(i+1)*10, 0))
        lineSet4.draw(win)

    circle1 = Circle(Point(0, 100), 100)
    circle1.setOutline("red")
    circle1.draw(win)

    circle2 = Circle(Point(100, 0), 100)
    circle2.setOutline("blue")
    circle2.draw(win)
```

Comment: what is `Vesica Piscis shape` ? Add link to some description and image.

Answer (score 0):

`Graphics` use `Tkinter` in background which has more usefull functions.

It can draw `arc`, `chord`, `pie`.

Tkinter: [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) and [more](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm)

```
from graphics import *

# --- constants ---

WIDTH = 300
HEIGHT = 300

# --- main ----

win = GraphWin("Patch", WIDTH, HEIGHT)

bbox = (5, 5, WIDTH-5, HEIGHT-5)

win.create_arc(bbox, fill="red", outline='green', width=3, start=0,   extent=90, style='arc')
win.create_arc(bbox, fill="red", outline='green', width=3, start=95,  extent=90, style='chord')
win.create_arc(bbox, fill="red", outline='green', width=3, start=190, extent=90, style='pieslice')

# --- wait for mouse click ---

#win.getKey()
win.getMouse()

win.close()
```

[image]

---

**BTW:** using `win.after(miliseconds, function_name)` to execute periodically function which moves objects.

```
from graphics import *

# --- constants ---

WIDTH = 300
HEIGHT = 300

# --- functions ---

def moves():

    # move figure 1    
    s = win.itemcget(fig1, 'start')        # get option
    win.itemconfig(fig1, start=float(s)+5) # set option

    # move figure 2
    s = win.itemcget(fig2, 'start')
    win.itemconfig(fig2, start=float(s)+5)

    # move figure 3
    s = win.itemcget(fig3, 'start')
    win.itemconfig(fig3, start=float(s)+5)

    # run again after 100ms (0.1s)
    win.after(100, moves)

# --- main ----

win = GraphWin("Patch", WIDTH, HEIGHT)

bbox = (5, 5, WIDTH-5, HEIGHT-5)

fig1 = win.create_arc(bbox, fill="red", outline='green', width=3, start=0,   extent=90, style='arc')
fig2 = win.create_arc(bbox, fill="red", outline='green', width=3, start=95,  extent=90, style='chord')
fig3 = win.create_arc(bbox, fill="red", outline='green', width=3, start=190, extent=90, style='pieslice')

# run first time
moves()

#win.getKey()
win.getMouse()

win.close()
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
from graphics import *

# --- constants ---

WIDTH = 300
HEIGHT = 300

# --- main ----

win = GraphWin("Patch", WIDTH, HEIGHT)

win.create_arc((0, -75, 300, 300-75), fill="blue", outline="blue", extent=120, style='chord', start=30+180)
win.create_arc((0, 75, 300, 300+75),  fill="blue", outline="blue", extent=120, style='chord', start=30)

win.create_oval((100, 100, 200, 200), fill="white", outline="white")
win.create_oval((130, 130, 170, 170), fill="black", outline="black")

#win.getKey()
win.getMouse()

win.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> keeping all the lines, within the intersection of the two circles
>   forming the Vesica Piscis shape

After multiple readings of your question and studying the figure, I believe I understand what you want.  The solution has nothing to do with the underlying graphics objects but rather mathematics.  We need to find where the secants intersect the circles to make them into chords:

```
from graphics import *

def intersection(center, radius, p1, p2):

    dx, dy = p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y

    a = dx**2 + dy**2
    b = 2 * (dx * (p1.x - center.x) + dy * (p1.y - center.y))
    c = (p1.x - center.x)**2 + (p1.y - center.y)**2 - radius**2

    discriminant = b**2 - 4 * a * c
    assert (discriminant > 0), 'Not a secant!'

    t = (-b + discriminant**0.5) / (2 * a)

    x = dx * t + p1.x
    y = dy * t + p1.y

    return Point(x, y)

def canvas(win):
    radius = 100

    center = Point(0, 100)  # Red circle

    circle = Circle(center, radius)
    circle.setOutline('red')
    circle.draw(win)

    for i in range(1, 10 + 1):

        p1 = Point(0, 0)
        p2 = Point(100, i * 10)
        p3 = intersection(center, radius, p1, p2)

        Line(p1, p3).draw(win)

        p1 = Point(100, 100)
        p2 = Point(100 - i * 10, 0)
        p3 = intersection(center, radius, p1, p2)

        Line(p1, p3).draw(win)

    center = Point(100, 0)  # Blue circle

    circle = Circle(center, radius)
    circle.setOutline('blue')
    circle.draw(win)

    for i in range(1, 10 + 1):

        p1 = Point(0, 0)
        p2 = Point(i * 10, 100)
        p3 = intersection(center, radius, p1, p2)

        Line(p1, p3).draw(win)

        p1 = Point(100, 100)
        p2 = Point(0, 100 - i * 10)
        p3 = intersection(center, radius, p1, p2)

        Line(p1, p3).draw(win)

win = GraphWin('Patch', 100, 100)

canvas(win)

win.getMouse()
```

The math can likely be simplified but I've written it out as this is not something I work with often.

OUTPUT

[image]